Docker compose env variables not working in Vue3 app
I built a QR Code generator and I want to dockerize it. The frontend of the app I built it with Vuetify,  so it uses Vite and Vue3. Inside the frontend I have a .env file with the api url and the port the app should start on. The problem that I'm having is that when I pass the env variables through docker compose the frontend service doesn't use the values from docker-compose but it uses the values from it's own .env file.
My project structure looks like this:
qr-code-generator
|----frontend
|    |----src
|    |----Dockerfile
|    |----.dockerignore
|    |----.env # only has the frontend variables (VITE_API_URL, VITE_APP_PORT)
|    |----...
|----backend # works fine
|    |----src
|    |----Dockerfile
|    |----.dockerignore
|    |----.env # only has the backend variables (PORT, MAX_CACHE_SIZE, CACHE_EXPIRATION_TIME)
|    |----...
|----docker-compose.yml
|----.env

The variables for the backend work perfectly fine. They use the values that I pass from docker-compose.
For example, this is my docker-compose.yml (to run it I use docker-compose up -d):
services:
  backend:
    container_name: backend
    image: alflyingwhale/qr-code-generator-backend:1.0
    volumes:
      - ./qr-code-generator-backend/logs:/var/server/logs
    ports:
      - "${BACKEND_PORT}:${BACKEND_PORT}"
    environment:
      - PORT=${BACKEND_PORT}
      - CACHE_EXPIRATION_TIME=${CACHE_EXPIRATION_TIME}
      - MAX_CACHE_SIZE=${MAX_CACHE_SIZE}
    env_file:
      - .env

  frontend:
    container_name: frontend
    image: alflyingwhale/qr-code-generator-frontend:1.0
    ports:
      - "${VITE_APP_PORT}:${VITE_APP_PORT}"
    environment:
      - VITE_APP_PORT=${VITE_APP_PORT}
      - VITE_API_URL=${VITE_API_URL}
    env_file:
      - .env

And this is the Dockerfile of my frontend service:
# Use the official Node.js image
FROM node:20-alpine

# Create and change to the app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Copy package.json and package-lock.json
COPY package*.json ./

# Install dependencies
RUN npm install

# Copy the rest of the application code
COPY . .

# Build the application
RUN npm run build

# Expose the port the app runs on
EXPOSE 3000

# Start the application
CMD ["npm", "run", "preview", "--host", "0.0.0.0"]

The .env file that the docker-compose file uses looks like this:
VITE_APP_PORT=5000
VITE_API_URL=http://pedro2:8080/api/generate?
BACKEND_PORT=8080
CACHE_EXPIRATION_TIME=3600
MAX_CACHE_SIZE=100

And if I run docker exec -it {id} sh and then use env. I get the following result:
...
VITE_APP_PORT=5000
VITE_API_URL=http://pedro2:8080/api/generate?

Which means the variables are in the container. However, in my frontend image I have a .env file with the same variables but the following values:
VITE_APP_PORT=3000
VITE_API_URL=http://localhost:8080/api/generate?

In the frontend I'm accessing the variables like this: import.meta.env.VITE_API_URL.
Now, when I do a console.log in the frontend, I get PORT=3000 and API_URL=http://localhost:8080/api/generate?.
However, in the vite.config.mts file, I have this setup, and the app starts in the port that I setup in the docker-compose env variable:
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    Vue({
      template: { transformAssetUrls },
    }),
    // https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify-loader/tree/master/packages/vite-plugin#readme
    Vuetify(),
    Components(),
    ViteFonts({
      google: {
        families: [{
          name: 'Roboto',
          styles: 'wght@100;300;400;500;700;900',
        }],
      },
    }),
  ],
  define: { 'process.env': {} }, # Should I write the variables here?
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url)),
    },
    extensions: [
      '.js',
      '.json',
      '.jsx',
      '.mjs',
      '.ts',
      '.tsx',
      '.vue',
    ],
  },
  server: {
    port: parseInt(process.env.VITE_APP_PORT), # This properly sets it to port 5000 from docker-compose
  },
  preview: {
    port: parseInt(process.env.VITE_APP_PORT), # This properly sets it to port 5000 from docker-compose
  },
})

So the problem that I'm having is with the VITE_API_URL variable.
The app works with the url "http://localhost:8080/api/generate?" however if I want to deploy it on kubernetes I can't use localhost, so I need to pass the url through an env variable
I've been trying to solve this issue for a while now,
Should I include ENV variables in the Dockerfile?
Should I remove the .env file from the frontend service with .dockerignore so it only has the env variables from docker-compose?
Things I've tried:

I tried removing the .env file from the frontend, leaving only the env variables from the frontend, however then when I use console.log in the frontend or when I try to call my API the variables return undefined.

I'm only really having trouble with the VITE_API_URL variable, the ones for the backend work correctly and the VITE_APP_PORT variable works fine. This is my .env file:


VITE_APP_PORT=5000
VITE_API_URL=http://pedro2:8080/api/generate?
BACKEND_PORT=2000
CACHE_EXPIRATION_TIME=3600
MAX_CACHE_SIZE=100

Which leads me to believe that vite.config.mts is receiving the correct values from docker-compose, but when I try to use the env variables inside a component like this: import.meta.env.VITE_API_URL then it only uses the values from the .env file inside the frontend and no the ones from docker-compose.

If I run docker exec -it {frontend container id} sh and then use env. I get the correct values from the docker-compose. However if I do a console.log inside a component of the vue app, I get the values from the .env file inside of the frontend directory.

*** UPDATE ***
If I build the Dockerfile and then run the container with the following command:
docker run --name frontend_test -p 3000:3000 -e VITE_API_URL='http://testing.com/api/generate?' -e VITE_APP_PORT='3000' 'frontend_test'

And once again I run the command docker exec -it {id} sh, docker prints the correct values that I passed, however in the app, the console.logs still print and use the values from the .env file inside of the frontend directory.
Not sure how to solve this.
